# Which algorithm do I use to find the line center of a gaussian curve?

Tags: algorithms

Which algorithm do I use to find the line center on the image below?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gaussian curve has equation
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}((x-\mu)^2/\sigma^2},$$
where $\mu$ is the expectation and $\sigma^2$ the variance.

If you look for its maximum, you should solve for $f'(x)=0$ which gives you essentially $x-\mu=0$, hence $x=\mu$. The corresponding value is obtained computing $f(\mu)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}$, therefore the value that you are looking for is $\frac{1}{2}f(\mu)$.

Comment: Where is $\sigma$ in the graph shown?

Comment: The maximum of the function is for $x=\mu$ and is $f(\mu)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}$. So it is related to the 'vertex' of the curve.

Comment: And how do I find the vertex of the curve?

Comment: oh man... the x-coordinate of the vertex is $\mu$, the y-coordinate of the vertex is $f(\mu)$...